# TypeScript doesn't show error in React Hook for Pick type

Tags: reactjs, typescript

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-forked-bbrgpe?file=/src/App.tsx

```
import { useMemo, useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  type TTest = {
    t1: string;
    t2: string;
  };

  // no error here
  const [testState] = useState<Pick<TTest, "t1">>(() => ({
    t1: "testState1",
    t2: "2",
    t3: "3"
  }));

  // no error here too
  const testMemo = useMemo<Pick<TTest, "t1">>(
    () => ({
      t1: "testMemo1",
      t2: "2",
      t3: "3"
    }),
    []
  );

  // error here, on key t2
  const testConst: Pick<TTest, "t1"> = {
    t1: "testConst1",
    t2: "2",
    t3: "3"
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {testState.t1}/{testState.t2}/{testState.t3}
      <br />
      {testMemo.t1}/{testMemo.t2}/{testMemo.t3}
      <br />
      {testConst.t1}/{testConst.t2}/{testConst.t3}
    </div>
  );
}
```

3 variable with useState, useMemo, and just object with same type and key
but useState and useMemo do not show error on declaration
(Of course they show error when I try to access t2 or t3)

Why is this happening? Is there any way to know of a type mismatch at declaration time?

Change Pick to Omit, but same

Comment: It has to do with the excess property checking behavior of TypeScript: https://talohana.com/blog/typescript-excess-property-checks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're running into the excess property checking behavior of TypeScript. The reason why your `testConst` assignment throws a warning is because TypeScript performs excess property checking, but does not do the same for the returned values in your useState and useMemo.

Even though workarounds such as storing the object as a temporary const or using `as` for type casting exists, I would recommend you use the latest `satisfies` keyword introduced by TypeScript 4.9, which will ensure that your returned objects in those callbacks do not contain excess properties:

```
const [testState] = useState(() => ({
  t1: "testState1",
  t2: "2",
  t3: "3"
} satisfies Pick<TTest, "t1">));

const testMemo = useMemo(() => ({
  t1: "testMemo1",
  t2: "2",
  t3: "3"
} satisfies Pick<TTest, "t1">), []);

const testConst = {
  t1: "testConst1",
  t2: "2",
  t3: "3"
} satisfies Pick<TTest, "t1">;
```